# Cannot import Interaction Type Discord Components

Tags: discord.py

I have done the import of Discord-Components via `pip install --upgrade discord-components`in Shell

And then I imported into the code (line of import `from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle, InteractionType`)

but I cannot import InteractionType???

```
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle, InteractionType
ImportError: cannot import name 'InteractionType' from 'discord_components' (/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_components/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Try `from discord_components.interaction import InteractionType`

Comment: nope: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    from discord_components.interaction import InteractionType
ImportError: cannot import name 'InteractionType' from 'discord_components.interaction' (/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_components/interaction.py)```

Comment: Try ```from discord_components import *```

Comment: well, it simply works by **DISABLEING** the buttons

Answer (score 1):

[image: InteractionType is removed in 2.0]
`InteractionType` is removed in 2.0.0 as stated in the latest (gitbook) docs.
Docs link: https://devkiki7000.gitbook.io/discord-components/change-log/2.0.0#breaking-changes

Use integers to replace them.

- ChannelMessageWithSource = 4
- DeferredChannelMessageWithSource = 5
- DeferredUpdateMessage = 6

Comment: I have changed everything to the example in the docs but ```Command raised an exception: TypeError: Object of type Button is not JSON serializable```

Comment: Can you show your code that raised the Exception?